# Can you guess what I am

Tags: riddle

I can be extremely dangerous

I can’t be seen or smelt

I cause people to be confused

And I could even be in your house!

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> carbon monoxide

I can be extremely dangerous

> Lethal, in fact.

I can’t be seen or smelt

> It's a colourless and odourless gas.

I cause people to be confused

> [Symptoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide_poisoning) include dizziness and confusion.

And I could even be in your house!

> Occurs naturally in the atmosphere in small amounts.

Comment: Also it can confuse people about the effect on climate change

Comment: Safety warning on the last point: look closer at the article you linked in the second last point!!